# Microsoft.Graph C#: Make an API request programmatically

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, token

I'm working with Microsoft.Graph SDK and I need to get email SentItems programmatically in a class library.

I'm using the following code to create a client:

```
private static Graph.GraphServiceClient CreateClient()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

    // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
    // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
    var tenantId = "xxx";

    // Value from app registration
    var clientId = "xxxx";

    var pca = Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
        .Build();

    // DelegateAuthenticationProvider is a simple auth provider implementation
    // that allows you to define an async function to retrieve a token
    // Alternatively, you can create a class that implements IAuthenticationProvider
    // for more complex scenarios
    var authProvider = new Graph.DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
    {
        // Use Microsoft.Identity.Client to retrieve token
        var result = await pca.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        request.Headers.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    });

    return new Graph.GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
}
```

then I'm trying to use the client the next waay:

```
var sentEmails = graphClient.Users[authMail].MailFolders.SentItems.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

but I'm getting the following exception when executing the request:

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException'
> in System.Private.CoreLib.dll Exception thrown:
> 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

I thought that another option could be to get an auth token. I can get an auth token with the next code:

```
private static async Task<string> GetGraphToken()
{
    var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
    var instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    var tenant = "xxx";
    var clientID = "xxxx";
    var secret = "xxxxx";
    var authority = $"{instance}{tenant}";
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var credentials = new ClientCredential(clientID, secret);
    var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credentials).Result;
    return authResult.AccessToken;
}
```

And it just works, but then I don't know how to use it to do an API request programmatically.

Any of the two variants is OK for me, getting rid of the exceptions in the first case, or finding a way to use the token to make a programmatic SDK API call in the second.

What can I try next?

### Edit 1

I'm trying with the next approach, but the same exception is thrown:

```
var accessToken = GetToken();

var client = new Graph.GraphServiceClient(
    new Graph.DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        (requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }));
        
var mails = client.Users[authMail].MailFolders.SentItems.Messages.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example you trying to use IWA auth https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-integrated-windows-authentication?tabs=dotnet and it failing because there is interaction required. Most likely this is due to MFA being enabled on the account, generally you don't want to disable MFA so you either need to deal with the interaction and perform the other factor or use another method. You also don't have the correct scope for email eg Mail.Read would be required for

In the second method your using client credentials flow (but the older v1 flow) but if you want to use the Graph SDK it easier to just do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider but make sure you have the correct permission in your app registration and make sure its been consented to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response @Glen Scales. It ended up being I had no permissions to AZ portal. Now the support staff at my company supplied me the required permissions and everything's running fine, but your links are anyway very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Pls go to the api document to check the api permission required. For example, [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) required `Mail.ReadBasic.All, Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite` for application type. My code sample requires to use application type of api permission.

[image]

[image]

Pls consent the api permission and try code below:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var res = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].MailFolders.SentItems.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tiny Wang. Could you please let me know the url to access that API Permissions configuration resource in your screenshot? I don't have access to our Azure portal, and need to ask my tech lead, but don't know exactly where ir that.

Comment: open azure portal -> go to azure active directory -> app registrations blade -> select the azure ad application you used -> API Permissions blade -> Add a Permission -> choose Microsoft graph api -> choose application permissions -> find your required permission and pick them -> click add permissions button -> click grant admin consent for xxx

Comment: @TinyWang where in the Azure portal can be configured to which email accounts the Azure application has access to?

Comment: if you give the application api permission, every email address in your tenant can be accessed via this aad application. you can't set some of the email addresses denied to be accessed.

Comment: for azure ad + graph api, it offered 2 kinds of permissions, delegated and application, if you used delegated api permission for generating access token and call api, that means you need to sign in first to use the delegate permission, then you can only call api to get your own information, in your scenario, you can only query your own email address when you used delegated api permission. and for application api permission, permission is "big" because you can query all users' information, so it's not recommended.

Comment: anyway, you can try to use [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and test if you can sign in with your account and query some other's email.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response and explanation @Tiny Wang. My problem ended up being I had no permissions to AZ portal. Now the support staff at my company supplied me the required permissions and everything's running fine.